# php POST data not working as expected

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a page that post data to another page once a form has been submitted. I am guessing server. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
<form action="http://192.168.1.118/collegeShuttle/test/welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

It all great that I can do this on my second page and expect get the data back

```
<html>
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br />
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.
</html>
```

My biggest problem is that, when I navigate to that page from a different device or computer. I get error messages saying that those variables are undefined. My question is that if it claims to be posting to the server why cant I access it from different computers? If that is not the case, is there a way to send data to the server that I can access from any computer?

Comment: Which page are you navigating to from your other device? welcome.php? If so, do you think, POST data will be saved on the server once you submitted the data on a computer? That's not the case. You will always have to fill the form and submit it to get the data displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `$_POST` data is being sent to `http://192.168.1.118/collegeShuttle/test/welcome.php`, so are you getting the data in that page?

Comment: I am getting that from the computer I sent the data from. If I go to http://192.168.1.118/collegeShuttle/test/welcome.php from my iphone I dont see the data. The reason I am asking if because I would like to use that data that the user entered.

Comment: Are you resubmitting the data from the iphone? If you would like the data to persist across sessions, you would need to do something else like save it to a file or database (see other answer)

Comment: Any good resource on how I could save it to a file or database?

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST` variable is defined whenever someone sends POST data to your page (usually via form, like you have listed above).  The variable is only defined when POST data has been submitted to the page and will only be valid for that request (from which the data was sent).  If you open a different window resending the POST data, then it is lost.

Comment: Ha! I guess that answers my question. Is there any way to send data to the server that can be used later? I guess the `$_POST` wont help :-(

Comment: Use a database. Once you submit the data, save it on the database (if your using XAMPP or a hoster you'll most certainly have a mysql db)

Comment: Ok thanks! I have XAMPP installed and I would write a SQL query to do that.

Comment: @tawheed As you might have seen, I posted a link to a tutorial with MySql in another comment (http://tut.php-quake.net/en/mysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Post data has a resquest scope, if you want to persist the data on server probably wanna use a database.
Before you learn php you need to study the at less some of "http"

Answer (score 0):

because your second device does not have same value in cookie named phpsessid. If you want to work it that way submit the form from one device . Note the phpsessid cookie value , on second device create cookie with name phpsesid and put value you copied before . Now open the second page.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    <html>
        Welcome<?php echo $_REQUEST["fname"]; ?>!<br />
        You are <?php echo $_REQUEST["age"]; ?> years old.
    </html>
```